# Program that opens a binary file and creates an array using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, binary

This is the original question:

You will write a program in C that reads binary data from a
file. The first value in the file is an integer that indicates the number of floating point
values remaining in the file. The remaining data is the actual floating point values. Your
program must do the following:

1. The name of the input file is to be passed into the program as a command line
   argument.
2. The program will open this binary file, and read the first integer in the file. It will
   then dynamically create an array of floats of this size using the malloc function.
3. The program will then read the floating point values and store them into this
   newly created array.
4. Finally, the program will print out the floating point values in this array in reverse
   order, one value per line.

The output from your program ($./a.out data1 or $binread data1) should give

4.400000
3.300000
2.200000
1.100000

I have been trying to do this assignment,  but I cannot open the data files provided which are these:

http://tinyurl.com/zfwk3fu

http://tinyurl.com/jx4ne72

If I try to open them, I get cannot open or I get an infinite loop of 0

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you in advance

Here is what I have for code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int i;
   if(argc < 2){
       printf("invalid arguments\n");
   }
   else{
       FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
       if(fp != NULL){
           int n;
           fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
           float *arr = (float *)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
           for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
               fscanf(fp, " ,%f", arr + i);
           }

           for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i){
               printf("%f\n", arr[i]);
           }
       }
       else{
           printf("Can not open %s\n", argv[1]);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This line `fscanf(fp, " ,%f", arr + i);` will look nicer and clearer like this `fscanf(fp, " ,%f", &(arr[i]));`.

Comment: Do you get the printout "Can not open"...? If so you might want to have a look at errno, maybe using the perror function.

Comment: Secondly, it says to use binary files and data, so you might read them with `read` instead of `fscanf`. Do you want an example?

Comment: Yes please, I am trying, but I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: And yes I do get the can not open error

Comment: Try printing the error message: `printf("Can not open %s: %s\n", argv[1], sterror(errno));`

Comment: Common reason for open error is, the working directory of your running program is different from what you think it is. Try using absolute path to the input file and see if it helps.

Comment: Also, always, always check return value of `fscanf` and check for parse errors (read docs on what its return value means).

Comment: Let me see if that works..

Answer (score 0):

From the description you give, the file contains floating point values and nothing else.  You seem to assume that there are extra commas... If instead the values are just separated by white space, use this `fscanf` format:

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%f", arr + i) == 1) {
    /* float value was parsed */
} else {
    /* could not parse a float:
     * either unexpected end of file or invalid input
     */
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with this?

Comment: You use `fscanf` format `" ,%f"`.  `fscanf` will ignore any white space, match a comma (`,`) ignore more white space and parse a float.  Are you sure the values are comma separated? If so you should specify that in the problem description.  You should also check `fscanf` return value: it returns the number of formats correctly converted.  You want to complain if numbers cannot be converted, it helps locating problems and errors.

Answer (score 0):

> You will write a program in C that reads binary data from a file. The
>   first value in the file is an integer that indicates the number of
>   floating point values remaining in the file. The remaining data is the
>   actual floating point values.

Since you were to *write a program that reads **binary** data*, you couldn't use [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html), which is for **text** data. To *read the first integer* and to *read the floating point values and store them*, you can use [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html). Change:

```
13c13
<            fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
---
>            fread(&n, sizeof n, 1, fp);
15,17c15
<            for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
<                fscanf(fp, " ,%f", arr + i);
<            }
---
>            n = fread(arr, sizeof *arr, n, fp);
```